# Passing json object via ajax from jsp to javascript

Tags: java, javascript, ajax, jsp

How can pass json values from jsp to javascript as object via ajax?
I can not use global js variables in jsp because this will lead to json content to be visible in page's source

Here is the scenario that I want to achieve:

- url of jsp is opened in browser.
- Data is being created in scriptlet and coverted to JSON format
- json is "sent" to javascript as object

From above scenario, i understand that javascript must initiate the ajax call to jsp. 
The issue with this, that jsp's code will be invoked 2 times:

- When page is opened in browser - data is prepared
- on each ajax call same code will be called again

Constrains: No jquery, no other libs, no servlets, no additional jsps. :(

EDIT:

There is additional problem, I need to pass **multiple** json objects to javascript.
I wont be able to do it with `response.getWriter().write();`

I don't think concatenating all json objects and sending is the correct solution.

The parsing of the received object in javascript `http.responseText` will be overwhelming.

Comment: You could pass a parameter to differentiate the case of url and ajax.

Comment: When you say no servlets , jsp is compiled to a servlet finally.

Comment: @Tito Cheriachan I know that, I mean without introducing any other servlets :)

Comment: Did you try the suggestion by @alkis , in that way you can prevent two times execution.

Comment: "There is additional problem, I need to pass multiple json objects to javascript." Not a problem, pass back a JSON array containing the objects, then iterate over that array in your JavaScript code.

Comment: Also: "I can not use global js variables in jsp because this will lead to json content to be visible in page's source" If you're relying on an AJAX call as some kind of security mechanism so the user can't see the structure of the JSON object(s), you're wasting your time; viewing an AJAX call in any modern browser is pretty trivial.

Comment: yes, but it's not visible straight forward... and it's not for security reasons.

Comment: And there is another problem if I call ajax from javascript (after page is loaded) i get the obvious delay for ajax method to complete and returned to the page... I need the data before the page is displayed

Answer (score 0):

Why do you need ajax here? If you know that you need to populate some things from server onto jsp page you can do that through scriplets itself:

EX

```
<%@ page import="com.mypackage.PersonDAO" %>
<html>
<body>
<table>
<th>Name</th><th>Email</th><th>Contact</th>

<%
List<Person> myList = PersonDAO.getAllPersons();
for(Person person:myList)
{ 

%>
<tr>
<td><%=person.getName()%></td>
<td><%=person.getEmail()%></td>
<td><%=person.getContact()%></td>
</tr>
<%}%>
</table>
</body>
</html>
```

This is a very simple example. You can do more complex things using [JSTL](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/jsp/jsp_standard_tag_library.htm).. :)

So there is no jquery, no Servlets, no ajax and no extra jsp's :)

**UPDATE**

Since you want data in your javascript before page loads you can use jQuery's holdReady() method.

```
$.holdReady( true );
$.get( url, function() {
// Perform something
$.holdReady( false );
});
```

See but all modern browsers have developer tools like firebug for mozilla, so any ajax call made will be trapped by them. The only way you can secure them is my encrypting them.. which will complicate things for you... IF you can explain the scenario you are trying to implement may be I can come up with it..

Comment: As I said, I need to pass data to javascript function.

Comment: And what are you going to do with the data after passing them to javascript function? See.. Currently your question does not justify the need to pass data to javascript function..

Comment: @yuris Explain in detail the actual problem you need to solve, not just how you think you want to solve it. It may be that your chosen approach isn't the most efficient and there's an easier way to do it. For example, if the JSON isn't going to change between the page loading and the AJAX calls being made, there's no need to make any AJAX calls.

Comment: @Anthony Grist, I need to pass multiple json objects to javascript from jsp. I don't want json to be visible in page's source. json is not going to be changed.

Comment: @  DarkHorse as I stated in the post, no jquery